# how does mathjax work?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, mathml, mathjax

I'm using Mathjax in a project I'm working on but cannot figure out how it works. I'm using MathML with the following code:

```
<body>
    <math>
        <mi>x</mi>
        <mo>+</mo>
        <mn>2</mn>
    </math>
</body>
```

This code works fine.

My understanding of XML files was that they needed to be called and interpreted via AJAX, but MathML seems to be rendered through MathJax as soon as the page loads. Is there an `onload` method that renders MathJax as soon as the page loads? I've tried searching the documentation for a method that converts the XML to MathJax graphics but cannot find anything. I've also tried looking for some kind of map between XML tags and Mathjax fonts but havent been able to find anything there either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an `onload` handler that MathJax uses to typeset the page initially.

I'm not clear on what you are trying to accomplish, but if you need to modify the mathematics on the page after the `onload` handler runs, you will need to use the MathJax processing queue to issue a new typeset command.  See the [modifying math on the page](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/typeset.html) documentation.

There is no mapping between tags and fonts (the translation is more complicated than that).  Again, it would help to know what you are trying to accomplish.

The MathJax support community is more active on the MathJax [user forum](http://groups.google.com/group/mathjax-users) and the [developer forum](http://groups.google.com/group/mathjax-dev), so you might try asking there.

Davide

Comment: @DavideCervone--Thanks for the response. I'm trying to add a set of custom xml tags that are rendered by MathJax along with MathML tags. I figured if there was a map between mathml and the math graphics I could just add the set to it. I will check out the MJax dev forum but before I do, do you have any advice on how to do this?

Comment: MathJax only processes valid MathML, and inserting your own tags (outside of an semantics element with an annotation-xml tag) would be invalid.  On the other hand, it is possible to extend MathJax's tag set, but it is not for the faint of heart, and would require careful knowledge of the internals of MathJax, with additions in several places (both input jax, output jax, and several extensions).

Comment: It's not something I a can explain simply, nor is it documented at this point (as it is not really something that I expect people to do).

Comment: @DavideCervone--I see. Thanks for the heads up. Is the version available here:http://www.mathjax.org/download/ minified by any chance? I'm wondering if there is a version of code where the a's and f's are replaced by other (perhaps more meaningful) parameters?

Comment: @DavideCervone--I found a `createBox` method in the MathJax documentation inside `Accessible.js`. This method, if it does create an HTML box, could be helpful. Could you please explain what it does? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @codeninga:  the download that you point to contains both the minified and un-minified versions.  The latter have the more meaningful names, a more readable format, and some comments (when you are lucky).  Look in the `MathJax/unpacked` directory for the un-minified (human readable) versions.

Comment: `createBox` is part of the HTML-CSS output jax, and is an internal routine, not intended for use outside of that output jax.  It works in connection with `createStack` and `placeBox` to allow the HTML-CSS output jax to place elements using x and y coordinates.  These are not routines you should be calling by hand, however.  (Though you can certainly look at them to get ideas about how MathJax accomplishes its layout.)

Comment: @DavideCervone--The only `unpacked` folder I could find was in the `fonts` folder. Have I downloaded the wrong MathJax package?

Comment: Hmmmm.  How did you obtain your copy?  You can view the full file structure at https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/ where you should see the unpacked folder.